# Search over multiple combined Columns

Tags: sql

I have the following View:

[image]

I want to search there for, let's say: propertyname like 'Umax' and value_num = 550
but to display all properties from that part(s) (part_id) then. So in that case i would like to see all properties from parts 8, 10 and 11. 
And in addition I'd like to do that for more cases. Like: propertyname like 'Umax' and value_num = 550 and propertyname like 'Imax' and value_num = 5.5
which should show just all properties from part 8.
Maybe I'm trying it in the completly wrong way, but I'm really struggling at this point right now!

Comment: +1 for adding the screenshot. If everyone wrote their questions so well documented ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS()`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    tableName b
            WHERE   a.part_ID = b.part_ID AND
                    b.propertyname = 'umax' AND
                    b.value_num = 8
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for that!
So if I want to get more specific by adding another property I would add  AND EXISTS(...) with tableName c and so on. Or is there a more elegant way for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 where part_id in 
(select distinct part_id from table1 where propertyname = 'UMax' and <any other criteria>)
```

Replace `table1` with your table/view name. You can add other criteria like `value_num=5.5` and it should still work.